# Syntax Error when test component with SASS file imported

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying test my `React` component with `Jest` + `Enzyme`, but when my component has `SASS` file (`scss`), is occurring `SyntaxError`.

This is my SASS file content:

```
.user-box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

And I just import that in my component:

```
import React from 'react';

import './userBox.scss';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const style = {
            borderRadius: '99px'
        };
        return (
            <div>Hello World</div>
        );
    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Following error message of my test:

[image: Jest test error message]

If I comment the `import './userBox.scss';`, test will be okey.

How to can I test `React` component with `Jest` + ‵Enzyme` when has style imported

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You have do define a mock for this kind of file by define  [`moduleNameMapper`](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#modulenamemapper-object-string-string) in your jest settings.

We are using [`identity-obj-proxy`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/identity-obj-proxy). So install it with

```
npm install identity-obj-proxy --save-dev
```

and add it your jest setting:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
    "^.+\\.(css|less|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  }
```

Comment: I'm not understanding what is this configuration, but is working! Thank you so much, I will study about this

Comment: Thanks for this. You just saved me, im searching almost a whole day for a solution for this over the last week!

Comment: I tried all these options and no one worked for me. So frustrated

Comment: Didn't worked for me because I need the variables exported from the scss file, so I just ended crearing a js file exporting the variables, any idea for this situation?

Answer (score 60):

If you have [Babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel) in your stack, you can fix this in the right way using [babel-jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-jest)

Just do `npm i --save-dev babel-jest` and in your jest settings file add:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "^.+\\.(css|less|scss)$": "babel-jest"
}
```

Comment: I've already installed `babel-jest` so this is easier for me and works fine.

Comment: I dont use babel. I can use it just for this case? I tried this and don't work. Do I need any other dependency?

Comment: If you don't have babel, it is better to follow the solution in accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

*The following information wasn't available before, so I made a [pull request on **facebook/jest** and it was merged](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/5249).*

---

I wanted to stub style imported in modules, something like:

```
// module.js
import Style from '@/path/to/style.scss';
import App from './App';
```

So I created a style stub file:

```
// test/unit/stubs/style.js
module.exports = '.style-stub{color:red;}';
```

After messing around with the following `jest.conf.js`:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1', // '@' alias
    '^.*\\.scss$': '<rootDir>/test/unit/stubs/style.js',
}
```

I found that **the `moduleNameMapper` ordering is important.** The `@` alias rule was resolving before my `.scss` rule, so the style file was loaded as a normal module and would crash the test.

The solution is to put specific rules first.

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    '^.*\\.scss$': '<rootDir>/test/unit/stubs/style.js',
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
}
```

Comment: lifesaver !! I searched for hours and couldn't figure out what's going on... thank you !

Answer (score 5):

I have been searching for a while for a solution to a similar problem and I kept coming across the solution above.

I didn't seem to work for me at first but I realised that Jest was simply ignoring anything I added to "jest" in package.json. My setup includes a jest.config.js file. I found that if I added "moduleNameMapper" there, it worked. So now my jest.test.config.js looks something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  setupFiles: ["<rootDir>/testSetup.js"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^.+\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$":
      "<rootDir>/fileMocks.js"
  }
};
```