# Jest mock script tag before import

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, enzyme, ts-jest

I know that directly get document element from the component isn't good idea , anyway for example I have SomeComponent jsx file imported like

```
import SomeComponent from '../components/SomeComponent';

export default MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    SomeComponent.test ? "Hey" : "not Hey"
  )
}
```

inside of that component I have , element is a script with some content

```
const el = document.getElementById('element');
const json = el && el.innerText;
const info = json && JSON.parse(json);
export default test = info.someKey
```

Unit tests for MyComponent is something like this

```
describe('Tests for MyComponent', () => {
  it('should render without any problem', () => {
    wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    expect(wrapper).toExist();
  });
});
```

it failed with **TypeError: Cannot read property 'someKey' of null**

How can I mock **SomeComponent** script tag with **innerText**

Comment: You will need to render stuff for the document.get to find something. I am unsure if there is html with the id element in it?

Comment: I mocked it on the beforeAll(() => {
    el = document.createElement('script');
    el.id = 'element';
    el.content = {};
    document.head.append(el);
  });
it not works @ColinHale , I think import is working earlier

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56785464/mock-dynamic-html-element-in-jest it also not works @ColinHale

Answer (score 0):

It works when I mocked it on the setupTests.js file

```
const el = document.createElement('script');
el.setAttribute('id', 'el');
el.innerText = mock;
document.head.append(el);
```