# Jest test fails on import of .scss. Jest encountered an unexpected token. SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, jestjs, babel-jest

I can't get my tests to run.

When I run 'yarn test' for my react app, I get the dreaded error:
Jest encountered an unexpected token. SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Image: Jest Error

[image: Image: Jest Error]

It is failing on the import of the .scss from logon.tsx: `import styles from './_logon.scss';`
I have tried solutions such as the moduleNameMapper with 'identity-object-proxy' or with a style-mock:
[Syntax Error when test component with SASS file imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040269/syntax-error-when-test-component-with-sass-file-imported)

What am I doing wrong? I tried copying some of the jest config from the create-react-app as its working there. I put it in jest.config.js instead of package.json. Is this correct?

jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.{ts,tsx}', '!src/**/*.spec.{ts,tsx}', '!src/**/*.node.{ts,tsx}', '!src/typings/**/*'],
  coverageDirectory: 'build/coverage',
  projects: [
    {
      setupFiles: ['./jestSetup.js'],
      displayName: 'dom',
      testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
      testMatch: ['**/__tests__/**/*.spec.ts?(x)'],
    },
    {
      coverageDirectory: 'build/coverage',
      setupFiles: ['./jestSetup.js'],
      displayName: 'node',
      testEnvironment: 'node',
      testMatch: ['**/__tests__/**/*.node.ts?(x)'],
    },
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.(css|scss|sass)$': '<rootDir>/jest/cssTransform.js',
    '^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)': '<rootDir>/jest/fileTransform.js',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$', '^.+\\.(css|sass|scss)$'],
  modulePaths: [],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
  },
};
```

_logon.scss

```
.logon-page {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.logon-container {
  background-color: $ui-01;
  color: $text-02;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 450px;

  :global {
    .bx--inline-notification__text-wrapper {
      width: 300px;
    }
    .bx--inline-notification {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    .bx--inline-notification__details {
      margin-bottom: auto;
      margin-top: auto;
    }
  }
}

.logon-container__button {
  float: right;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  height: 60px;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

.logon-container__input {
  background-color: $field-02;
}

.logon-container__hr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid $ui-03;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.logon-container__gap {
  height: 68px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "graphui",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production npm-run-all clean --parallel build:frontend build:server",
    "build:server": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.server.babel.js",
    "build:frontend": "cross-env IS_BROWSER=true webpack --config webpack/webpack.frontend.babel.js",
    "clean": "npm-run-all -s clean:remove clean:recreate",
    "clean:remove": "rimraf dist",
    "clean:recreate": "mkdirp dist/web/static",
    "commit": "cz",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development npm-run-all clean --parallel dev:frontend dev:server",
    "dev:server": "webpack -w --config webpack/webpack.server.babel.js",
    "dev:frontend": "cross-env IS_BROWSER=true webpack-dev-server -d -w --config webpack/webpack.dev.babel.js",
    "lint": "npm-run-all --parallel lint:js lint:css lint:commits lint:bundlesize",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext ts,tsx src ",
    "lint:css": "stylelint src/**/*",
    "lint:commits": "commitlint -e ./.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG",
    "lint:bundlesize": "bundlesize",
    "test": "jest",
    "validate": "npm-run-all --parallel validate:lint validate:gbvalidator",
    "validate:lint": "lint-staged --allow-empty",
    "validate:gbvalidator": "gbvalidator --pattern \"^(feat|fix|release|refactor|test|docs|build|ci|perf|styles)/([a-z0-9_#-./]){3,40}\\$\" --message \"See CONTRIBUTING.md for examples of valid branch names\"",
    "validated:translation": "node missingTranslations.js"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "commit-msg": "commitlint -E HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS",
      "pre-commit": "yarn run validate",
      "post-merge": "node postMerge.js"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{ts,tsx}": [
      "eslint --fix",
      "jest --bail --ci --silent --findRelatedTests"
    ],
    "src/**/*.{css,scss}": [
      "stylelint --fix"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@carbon/grid": "^10.15.0",
    "@carbon/icons-react": "^10.19.0",
    "@carbon/themes": "^10.21.0",
    "@carbon/type": "^10.16.0",
    "@egjs/hammerjs": "^2.0.17",
    "@emotion/cache": "^10.0.29",
    "@emotion/core": "^10.0.35",
    "@emotion/styled": "^10.0.27",
    "@loadable/component": "^5.13.2",
    "@loadable/server": "^5.13.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.4.0",
    "blueimp-md5": "^2.18.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "carbon-components": "^10.22.0",
    "carbon-components-react": "^7.22.0",
    "carbon-icons": "^7.0.7",
    "chokidar": "^3.4.3",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "create-emotion-server": "^10.0.27",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
    "express-winston": "^4.0.5",
    "gremlin": "^3.4.8",
    "helmet": "^4.1.1",
    "i18next": "^19.8.2",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.0.1",
    "i18next-fs-backend": "^1.0.7",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.0.21",
    "i18next-http-middleware": "^3.0.6",
    "ibm_db": "^2.7.1",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "immer": "^7.0.9",
    "java.io": "^2.4.0",
    "js-yaml": "^3.14.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "keycharm": "^0.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dnd": "^11.1.3",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^11.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-error-boundary": "^3.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.9.2",
    "react-i18next": "^11.7.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-window": "^1.8.5",
    "reactour": "^1.18.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "remove": "^0.1.5",
    "serialize-javascript": "^5.0.1",
    "serve-static": "^1.14.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "vis-data": "^7.1.0",
    "vis-network": "^8.4.0",
    "vis-util": "^4.3.4",
    "winston": "^3.3.3",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/node": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.1",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^11.0.0",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^11.0.0",
    "@hookform/devtools": "^2.2.1",
    "@lcluber/gitbranchvalidator": "^1.3.0",
    "@loadable/babel-plugin": "^5.13.2",
    "@loadable/webpack-plugin": "^5.13.0",
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.2",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^7.26.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.8",
    "@types/blueimp-md5": "^2.7.0",
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "@types/carbon-components": "^10.15.0",
    "@types/carbon-components-react": "^7.10.10",
    "@types/carbon__icons-react": "^10.17.1",
    "@types/carbon__type": "^0.0.1",
    "@types/classnames": "^2",
    "@types/compression": "^1.7.0",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/eslint": "^7.2.4",
    "@types/eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.8",
    "@types/gremlin": "^3.4.6",
    "@types/i18next-fs-backend": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/ibm_db": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.14",
    "@types/js-yaml": "^3.12.5",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.0",
    "@types/loadable__component": "^5.13.1",
    "@types/loadable__server": "^5.12.3",
    "@types/loadable__webpack-plugin": "^5.7.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4",
    "@types/mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/mkdirp": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^14.11.8",
    "@types/node-sass": "^4.11.1",
    "@types/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/passport": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.3",
    "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.33",
    "@types/prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "@types/prop-types": "^15.7.3",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.52",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.9",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.6",
    "@types/react-window": "^1.8.2",
    "@types/reactour": "^1.17.1",
    "@types/rimraf": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/serialize-javascript": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/serve-static": "^1.13.5",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.4",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/terser-webpack-plugin": "^4",
    "@types/testing-library__jest-dom": "^5.9.4",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "@types/webpack": "^4.41.22",
    "@types/webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.15.3",
    "@types/webpack-node-externals": "^2.5.0",
    "@types/workbox-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.4.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.4.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.5.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-emotion": "^10.0.33",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "bundlesize": "^0.18.0",
    "chalk": "^4.1.0",
    "commitizen": "^4.2.1",
    "commitlint": "^11.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.2.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "cz-conventional-changelog": "^3.3.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint": "^7.11.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.12.0",
    "eslint-config-react": "^1.1.7",
    "eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "^5.1.2",
    "eslint-import-resolver-node": "^0.3.4",
    "eslint-plugin-generic-intl": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.1.2",
    "husky": "^4.3.0",
    "jest": "^26.5.3",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen": "^1.0.1",
    "jest-transform-css": "^2.1.0",
    "lint-staged": "^10.4.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "mkdirp": "^1.0.4",
    "msw": "^0.21.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.5",
    "nodemon-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.2",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "open": "^7.3.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
    "postcss": "^8.1.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.0.4",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
    "preload-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "prettier-eslint": "^11.0.0",
    "react-refresh": "^0.8.3",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "stylelint": "^13.7.2",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^8.0.2",
    "stylelint-config-sass-guidelines": "^7.1.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^20.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-styled-components": "^0.1.1",
    "stylelint-prettier": "^1.1.2",
    "supertest": "^5.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.3",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3",
    "typescript-plugin-css-modules": "^2.7.0",
    "unicoderegexp": "^0.4.1",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^2.5.2",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

babel.config.js

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const path = require('path');

const browsers = ['last 2 Chrome versions', 'last 2 Safari versions', 'last 2 Edge versions', 'Firefox ESR'];

const { env } = process;

const plugins = [
  'emotion',
  '@loadable/babel-plugin',
  '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining',
  '@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator',
  ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
  ['@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods', { loose: true }],
  [
    'babel-plugin-module-resolver',
    {
      alias: {
        '@frontend': path.resolve(process.cwd(), path.join('src', 'frontend')),
        '@server': path.resolve(process.cwd(), path.join('src', 'server')),
        '@shared': path.resolve(process.cwd(), path.join('src', 'shared')),
        '@typings': path.resolve(process.cwd(), path.join('src', 'typings')),
        '@testhelpers': path.resolve(process.cwd(), path.join('src', 'testhelpers')),
      },
      extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.json'],
    },
  ],
];

const targets = {
  browsers,
  node: 'current',
};

if (env.IS_BROWSER) {
  delete targets.node;
} else {
  delete targets.browser;
}

const presets = [
  [
    '@babel/preset-react',
    {
      runtime: 'automatic',
    },
  ],
  [
    '@babel/preset-env',
    {
      shippedProposals: true,
      targets,
    },
  ],
  '@babel/preset-typescript',
];

if (env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && env.IS_BROWSER) {
  plugins.unshift(['react-refresh/babel', { skipEnvCheck: true }]);
}

const config = {
  plugins,
  presets,
  env: {
    debug: {
      sourceMaps: 'inline',
      retainLines: true,
    },
    development: {
      compact: false,
    },
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

webpack.base.js

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import path from 'path';
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from 'mini-css-extract-plugin';

const {
  env: { NODE_ENV },
} = process;

const IS_PROD = NODE_ENV === 'production';
const rootDirectory = path.join(__dirname, '..');

const nodeModules = path.join(rootDirectory, 'node_modules');

const config = {
  mode: IS_PROD ? 'production' : 'development',
  performance: { hints: false },
  devtool: IS_PROD ? 'cheap-module-source-map' : 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(s?)css$/,
        sideEffects: true,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              hmr: !IS_PROD,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: {
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
                exportLocalsConvention: 'dashesOnly',
              },
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              additionalData: `
              $feature-flags: (
                enable-css-custom-properties: true,
                grid-columns-16: true,
                ui-shell: true,
              );

              @import 'carbon-components/scss/globals/scss/vars';
              @import '@carbon/type/scss/styles';
              `,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /node_modules\/vis-.*\.js$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        exclude: {
          test: /node_modules/,
          exclude: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'vis-network'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'vis-data'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'vis-utils'),
          ],
        },
        test: /\.(t|j)sx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? '[name].css' : '[name].[contenthash].css',
      chunkFilename: NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? '[name].[id].css' : '[name].[id].[contenthash].css',
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.tsx', '.ts', '.json', '.css', '.scss'],
    modules: [path.resolve(nodeModules), path.resolve(rootDirectory)],
  },
  stats: {
    cached: false,
    colors: true,
    entrypoints: false,
    children: false,
  },
};

export default config;
```

Comment: Here's a link that can help you where somebody said they used jest-transform-css https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3094

Comment: @AlePlo Thanks for the suggestion; however, I just tried that and it did not make a difference.

Comment: Hi, @Tom did you find the solution? If you found it. Can you please answer it? I am facing the same issue.