# toHaveStyles not working with module.css styles using React testing library with Jest

Tags: css, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have this component for which I am writing test case using react testing library
I am facing an issue with styles when the styles is imported from  .module.css file but works fine when I use styled components(style.js)

**Demo.js**

```
import styles from 'components/Demo/demo.module.css'
const Demo = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p className={styles.newText} data-testid="closeIcon">
        hello
      </p>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Demo
```

**Demo.test.js**

```
import Demo from 'components/Demo/Demo'
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
describe('Demo Component', () => {
  it('Component renders without crashing', () => {
    render(<Demo />)
    expect(screen.getByTestId('closeIcon')).toHaveStyle({ background: 'red' })
  })
})
```

**demo.module.css**

```
.newText {
  background-color: red;
}
```

But when I use styles.js it works ->
**styles.js**

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  icon: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
}))
export default useStyles
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please tell us what your jest.config.js looks like?

As a general rule, SASS and CSS are often excluded from jest because of errors.

In the following example, identity-obj-proxy is used to take the className of the style, but the application of the style itself is mock.

[Syntax Error when test component with SASS file imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040269/syntax-error-when-test-component-with-sass-file-imported)